# Unhandled Runtime Error Error: Request failed with status code 500 (NextJS)

Tags: next.js, axios, stripe-payments, http-status-code-500

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DF68MNDxVwU&t=14621s) on cloning Amazon and I have the exact same code as in the video but keep getting an error. I created new keys (Firebase and Stripe) and even changed the Shipping Rates in Stripe. The error is shown in the screenshot below. [image: screenshot] The code is in this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/joanskenderi/Amazon-Clone).
This is the component where I'm calling the secret key:

```
const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

export default async (req, res) => {
  const { items, email } = req.body;

  const transformedItems = items.map((item) => ({
    price_data: {
      currency: "gbp",
      unit_amount: item.price * 100,
      product_data: {
        name: item.title,
        images: [item.image],
        description: item.description,
      },
    },
    quantity: 1,
  }));

  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: ["card"],
    shipping_options: [
      {
        shipping_rates: ["shr_1M97piHPvZNNoU6bvw5ut7Oy"],
      },
    ],
    shipping_address_collection: {
      allowed_countries: ["GB", "US", "CA"],
    },
    line_items: transformedItems,
    mode: "payment",
    success_url: `${process.env.HOST}/success`,
    cancel_url: `${process.env.HOST}/checkout`,
    metadata: {
      email,
      images: JSON.stringify(items.map((item) => item.image)),
    },
  });
  res.status(200).json({ id: session.id });
};
```

This is the checkout component:

```
import Image from "next/image";
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import CheckoutProduct from "../components/CheckoutProduct";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import { selectItems, selectTotal } from "../slices/basketSlice";
import Currency from "react-currency-formatter";
import { useSession } from "next-auth/client";
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";
import axios from "axios";

const stripePromise = loadStripe(process.env.stripe_public_key);

function Checkout() {
  const items = useSelector(selectItems);
  const total = useSelector(selectTotal);
  const [session] = useSession();

  const createCheckoutSession = async () => {
    const stripe = await stripePromise;

    // Call the backend to create a checkout session
    const checkoutSession = await axios.post("/api/create-checkout-session", {
      items: items,
      email: session.user.email,
    });

    // Redirect customer to Stripe checkout
    const result = await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
      sessionId: checkoutSession.data.id,
    });

    if (result.error) {
      alert(result.error.message);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="bg-gray-100">
      <Header />

      <main className="lg:flex max-w-screen-2xl mx-auto">
        {/* Left side */}
        <div className="flex-grow m-5 shadow-sm">
          <Image
            src="https://links.papareact.com/ikj"
            width={1020}
            height={250}
            objectFit="contain"
          />

          <div className="flex flex-col p-5 space-y-10 bg-white">
            <h1 className="text-3xl border-b pb-4">
              {items.length === 0
                ? "Your Amazon Basket is empty."
                : "Shopping Basket"}
            </h1>

            {items.map((item, i) => (
              <CheckoutProduct
                key={i}
                id={item.id}
                title={item.title}
                rating={item.rating}
                price={item.price}
                description={item.description}
                category={item.category}
                image={item.image}
                hasPrime={item.hasPrime}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>

        {/* Right side */}
        <div className="flex flex-col bg-white p-10 shadow-md">
          {items.length > 0 && (
            <>
              <h2 className="whitespace-nowrap">
                Subtotal ({items.length} items):{" "}
                <span className="font-bold">
                  <Currency quantity={total} currency="GBP" />
                </span>
              </h2>

              <button
                role="link"
                onClick={createCheckoutSession}
                disabled={!session}
                className={`button mt-2 ${
                  !session &&
                  "from-gray-300 to-gray-500 border-gray-200 text-gray-300 cursor-not-allowed"
                }`}
              >
                {!session ? "Sign in to checkout" : "Proceed to checkout"}
              </button>
            </>
          )}
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Checkout;
```

This is shown in the VS Codes terimanl: `StripePermissionError: This API call cannot be made with a publishable API key. Please use a secret API key. You can find a list of your API keys at https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys. at res.toJSON.then.StripeAPIError.message (/Users/joanskenderi/Amazon-Clone/node_modules/stripe/lib/StripeResource.js:216:23) at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>) at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) { type: 'StripePermissionError', raw: { code: 'secret_key_required', doc_url: 'https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/secret-key-required', message: 'This API call cannot be made with a publishable API key. Please use a secret API key. You can find a list of your API keys at https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys.', request_log_url: 'https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/req_duLaUMVrQ3aelr?t=1669643878', type: 'invalid_request_error', headers: { server: 'nginx', date: 'Mon, 28 Nov 2022 13:57:58 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/json', 'content-length': '453', connection: 'keep-alive', 'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true', 'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, DELETE', 'access-control-allow-origin': '*', 'access-control-expose-headers': 'Request-Id, Stripe-Manage-Version, X-Stripe-External-Auth-Required, X-Stripe-Privileged-Session-Required', 'access-control-max-age': '300', 'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store', 'idempotency-key': 'd678ecb5-f3a6-428c-90b8-60f6d58a5398', 'original-request': 'req_duLaUMVrQ3aelr', 'request-id': 'req_duLaUMVrQ3aelr', 'stripe-version': '2022-11-15', 'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload' }, statusCode: 403, requestId: 'req_duLaUMVrQ3aelr' }, rawType: 'invalid_request_error', code: 'secret_key_required', doc_url: 'https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/secret-key-required', param: undefined, detail: undefined, headers: { server: 'nginx', date: 'Mon, 28 Nov 2022 13:57:58 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/json', 'content-length': '453', connection: 'keep-alive', 'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true', 'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, DELETE', 'access-control-allow-origin': '*', 'access-control-expose-headers': 'Request-Id, Stripe-Manage-Version, X-Stripe-External-Auth-Required, X-Stripe-Privileged-Session-Required', 'access-control-max-age': '300', 'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store', 'idempotency-key': 'd678ecb5-f3a6-428c-90b8-60f6d58a5398', 'original-request': 'req_duLaUMVrQ3aelr', 'request-id': 'req_duLaUMVrQ3aelr', 'stripe-version': '2022-11-15', 'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload' }, requestId: 'req_duLaUMVrQ3aelr', statusCode: 403, charge: undefined, decline_code: undefined, payment_intent: undefined, payment_method: undefined, payment_method_type: undefined, setup_intent: undefined, source: undefined }`

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: `This API call cannot be made with a publishable API key. Please use a secret API key` - did you try anything like that in your code?

Comment: It says you need to have an API key from stripe , just create one for yourself and use the same

Comment: @NicoHaase the code is the exact same one I have on my GitHub repo, i just have the .env.local file which obviously i can't publish. il looks like this: 
```
# Authentication
GOOGLE_ID=key_goes_here
GOOGLE_SECRET=key_goes_here
NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000

# Stripe
STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY=key_goes_here
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY=key_goes_here

HOST=http://localhost:3000
```

Comment: @NicoHaase I also used a secret key and called it. idk why it is throwing this `This API call cannot be made with a publishable API key. Please use a secret API key`

Comment: Please share the code here, not anywhere else

Comment: @jarivak I created and used it and it gives me that error.

Comment: @NicoHaase just updated the question

Answer (score 0):

When using Stripe, you have two types of keys[1]

- **Publishable Key**:  Use this key in your web or mobile app’s client-side code.
- **Private/Secret Key**: Use this key to authenticate requests on your server when in test mode. By default, you can use this key to perform any API request without restriction.

It looks like you are using your publishable key (**STRIPE_SECRET_KEY**) instead of using the Secret Key when calling Stripe APIs from your backend server.

You can follow these steps in order to generate an API Secret key for your test mode[2] and use it instead for your tests.

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/keys#obtain-api-keys

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/keys#reveal-an-api-secret-key-for-test-mode

Comment: I did it this way and it gives the error above.

Comment: When printing the value of `process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY`, it starts with `pk_test_...` or `sk_test_...` ? you need to make sure that you are using the key starting with `sk_test_...`